# PHP regular expression replace beginning and end of string if match exists

Tags: php, replace, expression

could you please help me on this problem
I want in PHP to replace the begining and the end of a string if match exists, as example:

source strings :
`tr_abcdef_lang` or `tr_abcdef` or `tr_abcdef_cba`
I want to replace the string to have it like this:
`fk_abcdef` or `fk_abcdef_cba`

I mean if strings ends with `_lang` or `_language` to remove it, and at the begining replace everything before the first `_` with `fk`.

So more examples :

```
tr_abcdef => fk_abcdef
tr_abcdef_language  => fk_abcdef
x_abc_cba => fk_abc_cba
x_abc_cba_lang => fk_abc_cba
t_tablename_languages => fk_tablename
```

Comment: show us what you've tried so far... if you don't show any effort, people are less inclined to help you.

Comment: Hello, 
i tried patterns like these:
'/([a-zA-Z]*)_(\w+)((_translation)|(_trans)|(_languages))/

and 
'/([a-zA-Z]*)_(\w+)((_translation)|(_trans)|(_languages)|$)/

but if the last string (_trans) not exists , it fails !!

Comment: i found the solution and it looks like:

    $pattern = "/^([a-zA-Z]+?)_(\w+?)(_trans|_translation|_languages)?$/i";             
    $replacement    = 'fk_$2';
    $fk_field_name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tbl_name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who tried to help

i found the solutions and it looks like:

```
$pattern = "/^([a-zA-Z]+?)_(\w+?)(_trans|_translation|_languages)?$/i";             
$replacement    = 'fk_$2';
$fk_field_name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tbl_name);
```

Thanks again and best regards

Wael

Answer (score 0):

i solve your regex problem

```
$pattern = "/^([a-zA-Z]+?)_(\w+?)([_trans|_translation|_languages]*?)$/i"; 
$replacement = 'fk_$2'; 
$fk_field_name = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement, "x_abc_cba_gsd_lang");
echo $fk_field_name;
```

my code

Try this `~(.*?)_(.*)_(.*)~si`

```
preg_match_all( '~(.*?)_(.*)_(.*)~si', "x_abc_cba",$M);
$E='';
if($M[3][0]!="lang" and $M[3][0]!="language" and $M[3][0]!="languages"){
$E="_".$M[3][0];
}
echo ("fk_".$M[2][0].$E);
```

or try it without php regular expression

```
$String="x_abc_cba_lang";
$xp=explode("_",$String);
$xp[0]="fk";
end($xp);
$Ek=key($xp);
if($xp[$Ek]=="lang" or $xp[$Ek]=="language" or $xp[$Ek]=="languages"){
   unset($xp[$Ek]);
}
echo implode("_",$xp);
```

Comment: I need to call this script in a while loop about 15000 times, so i need something quick and works with few lines of code .

Comment: @user2214773 i suggest you didn't use  regular expression for this because   regular expression is slow.

Comment: i found the solutions and it looks like:

    $pattern = "/^([a-zA-Z]+?)_(\w+?)(_trans|_translation|_languages)?$/i";             
    $replacement    = 'fk_$2';
    $fk_field_name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tbl_name);